# How to list directory content over SFTP using fabric?

Tags: python, sftp, fabric

I can list directory content over ssh using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

```
output = run('ls /path/to/dir')
files = output.split()
print files
```

I can download and upload too over ssh using get() and put() of fabric.

My server support only sftp connection so I am not able to see directory content over ssh. I know fabric provide `fabric.sftp.SFTP` but not able to use it. I tried to understand code given in http://nullege.com/codes/search/fabric.sftp.SFTP not able to frame.

someone please give example code to list directory content over sftp using fabric.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

Comment: till now I am using that only :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Fabric how can I create a glob list from a remote path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844599/in-fabric-how-can-i-create-a-glob-list-from-a-remote-path)