# In Fabric how can I create a glob list from a remote path

Tags: python, glob, remote-server, fabric

With Python's [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/index.html) I want to transfer files to and from a remote server.

The list of files to transfer I need to generate from a glob expression like `*` or `*.txt` (and then apply some addional exclusions afterwards).

For the case of transferring *to* the remote it is easy to glob the list of source files, because the source is local:

```
[ f for f in Path(local_dir).glob(<my glob expression>)]
```

But how do I do this on the remote server? I have a connection to the remote established via `with fabric.Connection(...) as c:`, but I cannot find a `glob` method in the connection object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to utilize the `listdir` method of the `SFTPClient` object returned by [`c.sftp()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.sftp) to get a listing of all remote files, and then apply [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) with your glob expression:

```
fnmatch.filter(c.sftp().listdir(), '*.py')
```

Result: With the following remote directory,

```
$ ls
1.log  2.txt  3.py  4.csv  5.py
```

first listing the entire dir, then with glob:

```
>>> c.sftp().listdir()
['5.py', '3.py', '4.csv', '2.txt', '1.log']
>>> fnmatch.filter(c.sftp().listdir(), '*.py')
['5.py', '3.py']
```

Comment: Works pretty well. Thanks! Great to have a working example. (One thing though to be aware of is that remote globbing using this answer does *not* treat dot files differently to other files (while the `glob` module does so for local files)..